# Assigning string in SHM segment breaks the whole structure

Tags: c, shared-memory

I've got a problem that seems a little odd to me.

**For a quick overview:**

```
#define LENGTH 2048

struct ShmBlock
{
   int value_1;
   char str[LENGTH];
}

int AssignStr(struct ShmBlock* shm, char* str)
{
   if(strlen(str) > LENGTH)
       return -1;
   strncpy(shm->str, str, sizeof(shm->str));
   return 0;
}
```

Code is simplified but i tried to show the lines of code that is the cause of the error. Firstly of course i establish connection to SHM, and it seems to work fine, I can assign int value with no problem, but some strange things happens when I call AssignStr(), in general, string is not copied, and every attempt to call shm->str end up with segmentation fault, second thing that surprised me was that calling AssignStr() changed my int value to some random numbers. Do you know what is the cause of this issue? And why does this error affect int value? 0.o

Comment: More information is needed. Recommend posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You know, I assume, that `strncpy` doesn't null terminate the destination if the maximum length is reached?  That's often a setup for a later overrun.

Comment: At the top of `AssignStr()`, try adding this line: `printf("shm %p\n", shm);` a NULL or uninitialized value could explain a SEGV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, when you first allocate the ShmBlock, it is zero, so when you test

```
if (strlen(str) > strlen(shm->str))
```

`strlen(shm->str)` is 0 (the first char in NUL), so you just return -1 without copying the string.

Comment: To remove this problem I change it to compere strlen(str) to LENGTH, but it didn't change anything, it seems like strncpy does not assign shm->str.

Comment: So you probably have a trivial typo somewhere setting up or attaching the shared memory,